# C++, reading doubles from txt into vector, problems with reading the whole file

Tags: c++, vector

I have a text file with 2 columns of doubles with a tab in between, and try to read them into 2 vectors. My first problem is that it does not go through the whole file but starts in the last third. My second problem is that while it does push_back it converts the numbers in some other numbers.. I just can't get my head around it..

If I try to just put them all into one string vector it works without problems, but I need them as doubles or int for further processing

```
ifstream myfile("TextFile",ios::in);

if (!myfile) 
{
    cout << "Can't open" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return -1;
}



vector<long double> Datenx;
vector<long double> Dateny;
vector<string>lel;

string line;

while (getline(myfile, line)) {

    //  lel.push_back(line);

    string numberx = line.substr(0, 12);
    int pos = line.find("   ");
    string numbery = line.substr(pos + 1, 12);
    stringstream iss(numberx);

    long double x = 0.0;

    iss>> setprecision(10)>>fixed >>showpoint >> x;
    //cout <<fixed<< numberx << endl;
    //cout<<setprecision(10)<<fixed<< x << endl;

    Datenx.push_back(x);
    stringstream is(numbery);
    long double y = 0.0;
    is >> y;
    Dateny.push_back(y);
}
for (int n = 0; n < 100; n++) {
    cout << Datenx[n] << ' ' << endl;
}
    //  cout << fixed << Datenx[2] << ' ' << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
```

Part of input file:

```
0.0000000000    0.0006536954
0.0000000100    0.0005515555
0.0000000200    0.0005004856
0.0000000300    0.0001327819
0.0000000400    0.0006945514
0.0000000500    0.0007864773
0.0000000600    0.0001327819
0.0000000700    0.0007354074
```

Output: Datenx vector:

```
0

1e-08

2e-08

3e-08
```

...

Output: Dateny vector:

```
0.000653695

0.000551555

0.000500486

0.000132782
```

so the Dateny is kinda right.. it cuts the last digit

and the Datenx vector is total wrong..

Comment: Can you provide a small example input file, with the output you get from it, and the output you expect? Have you tried printing out the lines you read in your while loop, and the `double`s you parse from that? Right now, this is actually pretty good for a first-time asker, you include most of the code and a pretty good description of the problem, but you don't quite include everything necessary for us to reproduce it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], what is your input, what is the expected output, what is the actual output

Comment: You know about `std::istringstream`. I recommend that you use it to parse the line you read with `std::getline` (instead of your substring method). Like e.g. `std::istringstream iss(line); iss >> x >> y;`

Comment: And considering that the `x` and `y` values are related, I suggest you use a structure with those as members, and use a vector of that structure instead of two different vectors.

Comment: Lastly, why do you hard-code `100` for the loop outputting `Datenx`? Are you *sure* there are at least 100 elements in the vector?

Comment: so the file looks something like this
0.0000000000 0.0006536954
0.0000000100 0.0005515555
0.0000000200 0.0005004856
0.0000000300 0.0001327819
0.0000000400 0.0006945514
0.0000000500 0.0007864773
0.0000000600 0.0001327819
0.0000000700 0.0007354074

and i would expect that the left column is in the Datenx vector
and the right in the Dateny vector

but for the Datenx vector i get this output:
0
0
1e-08
2e-08
3e-08
and so forth Dateny on the other hand looks exactly as aspected..

Comment: ^^^^belongs [formatted in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54249558/edit)

Comment: i'm sorry.. how to show the file the right way with tables or smth ? im new to this website..

Comment: You can't do much formatting in comments, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54249558/edit) your question instead

Comment: There is a very big difference in how you parse `x` and `y` from the input sting streams. I recommend that you stop using `stringx` and `stringy` and the whole sub-string part completely in favor of the *simple* and *consistent* parsing I shown in my first comment. Will save you quite a few lines, and make your code much easier to read, understand, maintain, and debug. And it'll probably fix the problem you have as well.

Comment: i've edited my question

@Someprogrammerdude i use the same code for both x and y so i don't understand how i parse them differently?

Comment: `iss>> setprecision(10)>>fixed >>showpoint >> x;` and `is >> y;` is *very* different I would say.

Comment: true, but even if i delete setprecision(10)>>fixed >>showpoint it does not change the output

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. The values seem to be right, just in scientific notation. Use `cout << fixed << ...` if you want fixed-point notation. (Also set the precision higher, if you don't want the last digit to be cut.)

Comment: @yassin oh yeah you're right.. was just a brain fart of mine.. 
still a small question so the file is like 2000 values big.. if use cout i can't see the whole vector, even if i use n<2000 for the output loop
it seems it shows only a hand full at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to keep it simple first. If it works, you can add functionality.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<double> v1, v2;
  std::string line;

  std::ifstream myFile("input.txt");
  while(getline(myFile, line))
  {
    std::istringstream lineStream(line);
    double first, second;
    lineStream >> first >> second;
    v1.push_back(first);
    v2.push_back(second);
  }
}
```

I tried this, with the following "input.txt"

```
1.1    1.2
2.1    2.2
3.1    3.2
4.1    4.2
5.1    5.2
```

Comment: I'd suggest using [`std::stod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) instead of `atof`, but other than that I like this approach. No need to `close()` the file either - you might like to be explicit in the code, but I'd argue that using the RAII behaviour of `fstream` (i.e. the file is closed in the destructor) is safer and more idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ... I removed the `myFile.close()` from my answer and changed `std::atof` to `std::stod`

Comment: Why use strings in the first place? Why not `double first, second;` and skip `std::stod`?

Comment: @[Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude): because I wasn't aware, that this was possible with `istringstream` ... thank you for your hint :) (every  day I learn something new :) )

Comment: That's the nice thing about streams in C++: They all work the same. It doesn't matter if it's an input string stream or an input file stream, or the private stream behind `std::cin`. As long as it's derived from `std::istream` they all work the same.

Comment: Now I have a question according to my own answer ;-): What if I'd like to use `'#'` as delim instead of `'\t'`. I'd use a `lineStream.getline(token, '#')` approach. But how do I keep track of, which token is to be added into which vector (without counting in a static variable) ?!